# The entity has no primary key attribute defined

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm new to JPA and I have been struggling with this error for some time now. Eclipse is "saying" that my entity does not have a primary key defined, but I read a bunch of tutorials and this is the way that they all do it.

Example: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Example_embedded_id_XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings version="1.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_1_0.xsd">

        <entity name="BefriendableUser" class="com.projects.socialconnections.befriendableuser.BefriendableUser" access="FIELD">
            <embedded-id class="com.projects.socialconnections.befriendableuser.BefriendableUserId"/>   
        </entity>

        <embeddable name="BefriendableUserId" class="com.projects.socialconnections.befriendableuser.BefriendableUserId" access="FIELD">
                <attributes>
                    <basic name="numId">
                        <column name="befriendable_user_id" />
                    </basic>
                </attributes>
        </embeddable>

</entity-mappings>
```

Comment: @NeilStockton I did what you said and now I'm getting the error "null is not mapped as an embeddable" on the line that has the embedded-id tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is wrong, as was that link (now corrected - refer to the JPA spec for facts not wikis which are prone to error).

`embedded-id` should be under `attributes` element, and the attribute name in `embedded-id` is `name`, not `class`. See the XSD schema at http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd

Comment: I did what you said and now I'm getting the error "null is not mapped as an embeddable" on the line that has the embedded-id tag.

Comment: which would be the point where you actually post details of your classes, the exception + stack trace etc. Based on what you post this is all that can be advised